# java.lang.NullPointerException on link grabber in Java, Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, webdriver

I'm starting my adventure with Selenium and Java. I tried to create simple script that would create list of all links on site (it also checks if it's internal or external link). It lists link like I want, but then I get test failed and NPE error.

```
public class Link_Grab {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/TEST/LIB/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void teardown() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void grablinks() {
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");

        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        for (int i = 1; i<=links.size(); i=i+1)
        {
            if((links.get(i).getAttribute("href")).contains("amazon"))
            {
                System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("href") + " = internal domain");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("href") + " = external domain");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Here is error I get:

```
FAILED: grablinks
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazon.tests.Link_Grab.grablinks(Link_Grab.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

My imports:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Can you help me with it? I can't find reason of this error.

Comment: Your `imports`? Which is _Line no 36_?

Comment: Line #36: `List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));`

I added imports to original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here that, some of the **anchor tag** doesn't have **href** attribute and it throws null pointer exception. getAttribute method returns null if the attribute is not there. Also, the list index starts with 0. please try the following code.

```
@Test
public void grablinks() {

    String hrefvalue = null;

    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");

    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for (int i = 0; i<links.size(); i++)
    {
        hrefvalue = links.get(i).getAttribute("href");

        if(hrefvalue != null){
            if(hrefvalue.contains("amazon"))
            {
               System.out.println( hrefvalue + " = internal domain");
            }
            else
            {
               System.out.println( hrefvalue + " = external domain");
            }
        }else{
              System.out.println("element doesn't have href attriubte");
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last entry in the list you are retrieved (i=links.size()) is not there. This can be avoided by using the Iterator from the list in the following way:

```
for (WebElement element : links)
```

or if you insist on using the index it should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++)
```

Comment: Yes, I figured out that would be the problem when I started getting indexoutofboundsexception when I tried this script on facebook page.

 I have two questions. How should iterate on `if((links.get(i).getAttribute("href")).contains("amazon"))` if I use `for (WebElement element : links)`? Also now I'm getting NPE on mentioned "if" and I don't understand what's the problem now, what's wrong with this "if"?

Comment: In stead of using `links.get(i)` use `element` i.e. `if(element.getAttribute("href")).contains("amazon")` and do this for all future usage of `links.get(i)`.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I changed my code to use element, but I still get NPE error on that "if.

Comment: As Murthi pointed out below, you need to check whether or not the attribute is present before calling the `.contains("amazon")`method on it.